# trying to launch a macro when the value of a DDE range changes

Tags: excel, vba, dde

I'm a novice in VBA but still I need yo  execute a macro every time the value of a range changes. The marco is already written but if someone can help me with this issue, I will be very grateful.
Just as you know the changing range is a DDE link updating the range with a continuous flow

Thxs for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to Excel, so this may help: [automatically execute an Excel macro on a cell change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change)