# excel VBA run macro automatically whenever a cell is changed

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a simple way to get Excel to automatically execute a macro whenever a cell is changed?

The cell in question would be in `Worksheet("BigBoard").Range("D2")`

What I thought would be a simple Google inquiry is proving to be more complicated - every sample involved intersects (whatever those are) or color formatting or any other number of things that appear to be irrelevant.

Comment: Use the answer by Peter Albert. Don't be scared of the line with intersect, that's just so VBA knows which cells you are monitoring for changes. And where he has MsgBox, that's where you call your macro. This is the simplest way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [automatically execute an Excel macro on a cell change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change)

Comment: Could you please mark the answer that worked for you, so this question is no longer shown as unanswered? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by using worksheet events:

In the Visual Basic Editor open the worksheet you're interested in (i.e. "BigBoard") by double clicking on the name of the worksheet in the tree at the top left. Place the following code in the module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'to prevent endless loop
    On Error Goto Finalize 'to re-enable the events      
    MsgBox "You changed THE CELL!"
Finalize:        
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: this works very well thank you very much. in the interest of fully understanding, how does the expression intersect(target)...perform in more plain speaking?

Comment: It tests that D2 was in the range of cells / or the cell changed (ie  - part of Target). If not the code exits. +1 btw

Comment: `Insersect(rng1,rng2)` returns the range where both input range "intersect". therefore, if the intersection of the changed cells and D2 is nothing, something else was changed and you don't want the macro to procede. BTW: If it solved your problem, please mark it as the solution by clicking on the checkmark!

Comment: There is a similar solution in the official Microsoft documentation at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213612

Comment: +1 for telling me to use this code in the worksheet, I had it in a module and it wasnt working, as soon as I put it in the worksheet, it worked :)

Comment: this works really well. but I'm making some modifications to it, and I notice if I write jenky code, and it errors out, I'm never able to run this macro again, even if I rewrite the macro to it's original state. I think it may have something to do with the Application.EnableEvents option. Can anyone speak to this?

Comment: @MarkRomano you're right - in case of an error the enable events was not reset. I extended the code.

Comment: **Bug**: if your cell's data-validated, and you type a non-valid value, after Excel displays "This value doesn't match the data validation restrictions defined for this cell" and you clicked on _Cancel_, the custom message "You changed THE CELL!" will still appear not only once but twice, even though you didn't change the value.

Answer (score 21):

Another option is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    IF Target.Address = "$D$2" Then
        MsgBox("Cell D2 Has Changed.")
    End If
End Sub
```

I believe this uses fewer resources than `Intersect`, which will be helpful if your worksheet changes a lot.

Comment: Simpler and without the bug I mentioned in the selected answer.

Answer (score 2):

In an attempt to find a way to make the target cell for the intersect method a name table array, I stumbled across a simple way to run something when ANY cell or set of cells on a particular sheet changes. This code is placed in the worksheet module as well:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 0 Then
'mycode here
end if
end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In an attempt to spot a change somewhere in a particular column (here in "W", i.e. "23"), I modified Peter Alberts' answer to:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Target.Column = 23 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False             'to prevent endless loop
    On Error GoTo Finalize                       'to re-enable the events
    MsgBox "You changed a cell in column W, row " & Target.Row
    MsgBox "You changed it to: " & Target.Value
Finalize:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I was creating a form in which the user enters an email address used by another macro to email a specific cell group to the address entered. I patched together this simple code from several sites and my limited knowledge of VBA. This simply watches for one cell (In my case K22) to be updated and then kills any hyperlink in that cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("K22")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        Range("K22").Select
        Selection.Hyperlinks.Delete

    End If 
End Sub
```