# Excel VBA worksheet event stuck in constant loop

Tags: excel, vba

I've combined two SO questions/answers to create some VBA to automatically replace special characters in a cell (E6 in this example).

It works great for replacing special characters, but when I clear the cell (Select E6 and press Delete key), it gets stuck in a constant loop.

Code below:

```
Const SpecialCharacters As String = "!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),{,[,],}"  'modify as needed

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Cells(6, 5)) Is Nothing Then

        Dim myString As String
        Dim newString As String
        Dim char As Variant

        myString = Cells(6, 5).Value
        newString = myString

        For Each char In Split(SpecialCharacters, ",")

            newString = Replace(newString, char, "")

        Next

        Cells(6, 5).Value = newString

    End If

End Sub
```

I tried adding an `Else` statement to block the loop from happening but it did not work:

```
Else

    Cells(6, 5).Select
```

SO Question/Answer references:

[excel VBA run macro automatically whenever a cell is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337008/excel-vba-run-macro-automatically-whenever-a-cell-is-changed)

[Removing special characters VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356993/removing-special-characters-vba-excel)

Can anyone provide insight on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: add to your if to test if the cell is blank?

Comment: I guess I thought that's what `If Not Intersect(Target, Cells(6, 5)) Is Nothing Then` was handling.  So you mean add in an `ElseIf Cells(6, 5).Value = "" Then` type of thing?

Comment: No, that line is testing whether the target cell intersects with cells(6,5).  But look like @ScottHoltzman, has your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off the Event Handler before you write back to the cell. Otherwise, writing back to the cell fires the Event Handler again, and will never stop it.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Cells(6, 5).Value = newString
Application.EnableEvents = True
```