# How to count all cells with any background coloring using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to simply count all cells in a column that have a background color. Any color it doesn´t matter which one. I have used a module using this code:

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    For Each datax In range_data
        If datax.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
            CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
        End If
    Next datax
End Function
```

This works good when I apply the formula for the first time. It no longer reacts, when I change fill in the sheet. How can I exceute this function, every time the users edit a cell?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337008/excel-vba-run-macro-automatically-whenever-a-cell-is-changed)

Comment: Hi. thanks I saw that but I can´t get it working. I have only a module with that bit of code in it. In the Worksheet I call it like this =CountCcolor(B5:B18) which works fine. But if i fill new cells it doesn´t react. Sorry I´m new to VBA..

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the entire workbook by using the following code, in the relevant **Worksheet_Change** event :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Thsi event is not called when I fill a cell. Only when I remove the fill.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event which is triggered by filling a cell. Thus, I suggest the following worksheet macro

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Sh.Calculate
End Sub
```

in addition to your macro. Reasoning: after filling a range you will (eventually) select other cells on that sheet. At this moment, the sum is recalculated. It is not ideal as it's not updated ***while*** you're selecting the range, and it might be computationally intensive.