# How to fill a worksheet based on cell values from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets ("Worksheet A" and "Worksheet B").

Worksheet A has a list of tests. Each row represent a test performed. 
Column F has the value "Passed" or "Not Passed".

If "Not Passed", the entire row needs to be added automatically to "Worksheet B" which represent an action list.

Any suggestion on how to do this dynamically, i.e. without having to run a macro manually?

Comment: Obviously you could try the formula `=IF(Sheet1!$F1="Not Passed",Sheet1!A1,"")` in A1 of sheet B, and expand to your range, but this will leave blank rows between the entries on sheet B

Comment: Sounds like [worksheet events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337008/excel-vba-run-macro-automatically-whenever-a-cell-is-changed)

Comment: Its possible with , Evaluate , IndexMatch , but you need to try it first

Answer (score 0):

Use worksheet events. `Alt` + `F11` to open VBA interface:

Double click "Sheet1" on the left hand side of the interface and paste this in:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 0 Then
        update_sheet
    End If
End Sub
```

Below where it says "Sheet1", right click on "Modules". Hover on insert and click "Add Module". Paste the following code into the module:

```
Sub update_sheet()
    s1_rows = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    Set s1_rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("F1:F" & s1_rows)

    s2_rows = 1
    For Each cell In s1_rng
        If cell.Value = "Not Passed" Then
            cell.EntireRow.Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A" & s2_rows).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            s2_rows = s2_rows + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This can be improved, but should start you off.