# Splitting data from barcode into different cells in MS Excel

Tags: vba

I have a barcode scanner USB plug&play which is giving a string of data in one cell of Excel in this form 4449520450061198001
I want to split this data automatically in different cells everytime my scanner reads the code.
Please help.

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you require every digit in a separate cell? Are the barcodes all the same length?

Comment: So you need to wire the code into an event? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change If the scanner acts as a wedge does it add a new line on the end of the code?

Comment: Yes. i want macro to be run by an event. but how can i do that? everytime i scan new item, string goes to next cell down automatically. e.g. from A1 and then A2.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include an `event`

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const ws_range = "A1:A10"

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim codestr As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    codestr = Target.Text
    If Target <> "" Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range(ws_range)) Is Nothing Then
            With Target
                k = Len(codestr)
                i = 2
                Do Until i = k + 2
                    ws.Cells(Target.Row, i).Value = Mid(codestr, i - 1, 1)
                    i = i + 1
                Loop
            End With
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I haven't fully tested this but now after a value is inserted into column a it will be split into the cells to the right. Obviously modify `A1:A10` to match what you need.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for reply
I understand the code its working fine but how can i run this automatically?
i want these values to go into cells every time my scanner reads the barcode automatically without pressing any button.
Is it possible?

Regards,