# Adding a specific value to a cell every time a number greater than 0 is added to another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I would like cell `M6` to add $12.73 every time I add a number greater than 0 to `M7`.

Example:

I am doing payroll. For every day worked (Field `M7`) I bill $12.73 (Field `M6`). I do this every month, and need to keep a running list.

Instead of always having to put the number of days in field `M7` and then add $12.73 to field `M6`, I would like the +$12.73 to compute automatically when I add the number of days to `M7`.

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.How would M6 know to add $12.73 to its cell, when I make changes to M7? I'm not looking to multiply M7 by  cell M6, but rather add $12.73 to M6 every time I make a change M7. Please advise.

Comment: in that case look into VBA (`Worksheet_Change` event)

Comment: Going with @simoco on this one. VBA is pretty much the only way to do this, since oddly enough you're not multiplying them (maybe you have a base value?). However, caution on the requirement *everytime I make a change to M7* as that means a different thing in `Worksheet_Change` events. Simply editing the cell will trigger another $12.73 to be added.

Comment: Thanks. How would I write the formula to trigger the cell to add $12.73 when I change another cell?

Answer (score 0):

This couldn't be done with formula to the best of my knowledge. You could hypothetically add another cell which you manually increment every time you do something but a more elegant solution would be to use VBA to automatically increment the value of the cell by 12.73.

Take a look at this similar question. [Check updates automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change)

try this in the sheet that you want, the sheet object "me" will only work if the code is contained there and not in a module. As a side this will also add 1 to the value when the cell is cleared, but it should be enough to get you started:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A5")) Is Nothing Then Me.Range("B5").Value = Me.Range("B5").Value + 1
```

End Sub

Comment: Thank you kindly. I know what I want can be achieved, I just don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: Here`s a more succinct example.

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula into M6:
`=if(M7>0,"12.73","")`

Enter your days worked into M7, and M6 will automatically populate `12.73`.