# VBA excel not run unless i click play button

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know where i have gone wrong. The Script works but it doesn't automatically run unless i go into the VBA application and click the play button for the script to run. Can someone help?

```
Private Sub HideChart1()

    If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("User Interface").Range("F8") = "Yes" Then

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 6").Visible = True

    Else

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 6").Visible = False

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to run automatically ?

Comment: I can only assume that you are trying to create a Worksheet_Change event triggered by F8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a `Worksheet Change` event.

Untested, but should work. Put this in your "User Interface" worksheet module.:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
If target = Range("F8") And target.Value = "Yes" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 6").Visible = True
Else
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 6").Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

With `Worksheet Change`, I don't think (keyword "think") you need to specify the worksheet the `Range("F8")` is expected to be on, since it's by definition, the activesheet.  If you want though, add the sheet name before that to be sure.

Comment: Should maybe change `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook` for added robustness (assuming the chart is in the same workbook as the code)  Event handlers can run without the workbook necessarily being active.

Answer (score 5):

Handle `SheetChange`, and call your procedure in there.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    HideChart1
End Sub
```

Done. Don't implement logic in event handlers, it's the first Gate of Hell and spaghettification. Having a separate, dedicated procedure for it is **perfect** - all you need is something that calls it automatically.

If `HideChart1` is implemented in its own standard module, you'll need to make it `Public` to be able to call it from a worksheet's code-behind; add `Option Private Module` at the top of that module to avoid exposing members as macros and/or worksheet functions.

Comment: Can you expand a little, or direct to some resources, detailing why to avoid using logic in event handlers?  It's the first time I've seen this mentioned, and I'd like to know more :D

Comment: Ah, good points. It actually reminded me that one of my workbooks has a pretty convoluted `Worksheet_Change` event that would benefit from breaking out into their own subs.  Thanks for your comments, helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

If my comment is correct, then you'll need something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("F8")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Worksheet.Range("F8").Value = "Yes" Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 6").Visible = True
        Else
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 6").Visible = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

You can find more information about the worksheet change event here 
[automatically execute an Excel macro on a cell change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change)

The key takeaway from that question, is to put the code in the worksheet module, not a regular module, or the workbook module.