# Trigger code to edit a cell after a value entered in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, events

I wrote a macro to check the value being entered in some cells.

If the input is higher than 8 the excess is written to another cell and the input is changed to 8. If the input is lower than 8 the missing amount is written to a third cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
TA = Target.Address: R = Target.Row: C = Target.Column
If C = 2 Or C = 7 Then
  If (R < 19 And R > 11) Or (R < 33 And R > 25) Then
    Hours = Cells(R, C).Value
    If Hours <> 0 Then
      If Hours > 8 Then
        Cells(R, C) = 8
        Cells(R, C + 1) = Hours - 8
      End If
      If Hours < 8 Then
        Cells(R, C + 2) = 8 - Hours
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
End Sub
```

The problem is the macro is not executed when I enter the input, only when I select the cell again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your trigger event from **Worksheet_SelectionChange** to **Worksheet_Change**.

Second, you can optimize your code, since you can read the `Column` and `Row` property of `Target`, you can save a few rows in your code.

Third, I modified your test condition for checking the row, by switching to `Select Case` you can now add more rows to this condition easily.

Use `Target.offset` to insert the result in the neighbour cells.

I added `Exit Sub` so it won't run an extra time after you change the values here.

If you want, you can also remove the `Hours` as it is not needed (unless you have a global variable that somehow reads this value).

You can just use `If Target.Value <> 0 Then` etc.)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' check if target is in Column B or Column G
If Target.Column = 2 Or Target.Column = 7 Then

    Select Case Target.Row
        Case 12 To 18, 26 To 32  ' check if target row is 12 to 18 (including) ir between 26 to 32 (including)

            Hours = Target.Value
            If Hours <> 0 Then
                If Hours > 8 Then
                    Target.Value = 8
                    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Hours - 8
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    If Hours < 8 Then
                        Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = 8 - Hours
                    End If
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
    End Select
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `Worksheet_SelectionChange` only fires when the selected cell is changed. You should use `Worksheet_Change` instead. You can see this [automatically execute an Excel macro on a cell change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change) for more details.