# How do I update the date in a cell ONLY if a certain cell is modified

Tags: excel, vba, date, excel-formula, formula

I have it set up right now so when the cell data changes, it updates the date. When refreshing the workbook, it also updates the date, even if I haven't modified the cell contents.

I only want to update the date if I modify the cell contents. I am pulling my data from a CSV file so I constantly have to refresh every now and again. How do I get around this so that it only shows the date upon which a cell is truly modified?

I have a public function set up like this at the moment, but it does not work.

```
Public Function worksheetChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, [D4]) Is Nothing Then [L4] = Date

End Function
```

Even when I refresh the worksheet and I haven't modified the cell, it still updates the date, how do I get around this?

EDIT: I've come up with this type of VBA code, but I'm not sure how to get it working.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, [D4]) Is Nothing Then
If Not ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll Then [L4] = Date

End Sub
```

In hindsight, this code means that if the application doesn't intersect then take D4 and also, if the workbook doesn't refresh, update L4 as todays date.

Thank you.

Comment: Could it be that [D4] is recalculated when you refresh the worksheet, although the new value equals the old one?

Comment: I would assume so, it's pulling the data from the csv file when refreshing. I only want the date changed only if the cell contents change (ie. banana to orange, not banana to banana)

I've updated my code in order to get a grasp of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: How about some programmatic solution by saving the old value somewhere (say in another, hidden worksheet) and testing if the value has changed?

Comment: I guess I will have to resort to that if I can't find a solution, thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change)

```
Dim oldValue

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  oldValue = Target.Worksheet.Range("D4").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("D4")) Is Nothing Then
      If oldValue <> Target.Worksheet.Range("D4").Value Then
        Target.Worksheet.Range("L4").Value = Date
      End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It still updates the date even if the cell contains the same value as it did when refreshing. I'm only wanting to update the date as the cell changes contents; trying to evade the date updating when refreshing data of the same value.

Comment: It works, thanks! Now to find out how to make this as a function as I want to spread this across a multiple range of cells.