# Auto-filling cells between sheets

Tags: excel

Ok, bear with me here, I have a spreadsheet I'm creating that I want one sheet to only populate if there is information on the other sheet. So, sheet one would be "ORDER", sheet two "FILTER SIZES."  What I am trying to do is this, if I put in a quantity on "FILTER SIZES" I want it to auto populate on the "ORDER" sheet. But, if I leave the quantity blank then nothing transfers over. And I know I can just do the IF = between the two sheets but I don't want the 0 quantity there.  So, I'll try to put screen shots in of how I want it to look....new to this site so not sure how well that will work! [This is before entering any information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s22Un.jpg)

And this is how I want it to look if I enter information in some of the cells 
[With information entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHXXo.jpg)

So basically, I want the information to populate over only if I enter a quantity and I don't want blank cells in between.

Help?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change . Your best bet is to set your listening range to the Quantity column in the `FILTER SIZES` sheet, and move the row via vba then.

Comment: What is vba? Sorry, I'm good with excel on a more basic level I think? I can do spreadsheets but the more involved formulas like what I'm trying to do are new to me still.

Comment: I looked up vba......and, I think I'm more confused now than before haha. I know this must seem like such a simple way to do it, but it's gonna take me time to wrap my head around this.  Is there a way to maybe help me out and show me how to do exactly what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: It sounds like you are close. If you don't want your IF statement to give you a 0 when evaluated to FALSE, then just set the ELSE clause to "". As in IF(A1 = TRUE, "ok", "")

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Table` and by combining the `INDEX` and `MATCH` formulas.
Let me show you the result first:

[image]

We enter the formulas into the `FILTER` table, here shown as a picture on the right, the orange one.

The formula in QTY column is: `=IFERROR(INDEX(tblOrders[QTY];MATCH([@SIZE];tblOrders[SIZE];0));"")`

The formula for TYPE columns is: `=IFERROR(INDEX(tblOrders[TYPE];MATCH([@SIZE];tblOrders[SIZE];0));"")`

The `[@SIZE]` part in both formulas is the SIZE column in orange table.

If you need explanation of the formulas, let me know.