# Protect a row in Excel with a password after it was completed by user

Tags: excel, vba, locking, row

I just started with some basic programming using VBA and I'm trying to make a logbook in Excel in which different users have to complete a row with some data.

The goal is that the complete row is automaticaly locked (with password) when it was completed by the user.

Up until now I only found code in which a specific range is selected upfront. In my case the index of the row can be any number.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look up executing macro on cell change (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change) to get you started. Then when they fill out a certain cells you can check if all fields are filled out and lock that row accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a loop checking for each row, if the last mandatory column was filled, and if so, protect that row.
The user would have to press a button like "Update" or "Protect" each time they finish making some entries though.