# Copy and Paste Today's Date in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to create a function that auto-populates the current date in a cell only if the cell adjacent to it contains the text `Open`.

Similarly, I also would like the function to do the same if the status is `Closed`.

The main challenge with this code is that I do not want the date to change by using functions like `=TODAY()` or `=NOW()`, bht instead I would like these dates to be permanent once populated.

Here is an image of the table I am hoping to have this functionality work on.

[image]

In terms of code, here is what I was able to muster up:

```
Function add_todays_date() 

    If Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C5") = "Open" Then 
        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("G4").Copy 
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
```

Comment: You can do something like Cells(1, 1) = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy") but if you run the code it will overwrite with current date. If you want it to be permanant do an Isempty test on the cell first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine with an IsEmpty test to avoid overwriting cells you have already looked at and populated.

To demonstrate the principle:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    With ActiveSheet

        If IsEmpty(.Cells(1, 2)) And .Cells(1, 1) = "Open" Then

            .Cells(1, 2) = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Or in a loop construct:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim currCell As Range

    For Each currCell In ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B10") 'Adjust as required

        If IsEmpty(currCell) And currCell.Offset(0, -1) = "Open" Then

            currCell = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")

        End If

    Next currCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Great it works! I have one more quick follow up question, is there anyway to have this do the auto population without having to run the sub each time?

Comment: Yes, you have alot of options, look at this example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change)

Comment: You could tie it to a worksheet change event for example. You need to decide what the appropriate trigger would be and this may also depend on how frequently you want to add in the dates.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you want a function for this, they work like Excel worksheet functions, they might update the next time you open the workbook or refresh the worksheet.

```
    Option Explicit

    Public Function add_todays_date()

    Dim selected_range As Range
    Set selected_range = Selection

    With selected_range.Offset(0, -1)

        If .Value = "Open" Or .Value = "Closed" Then
            add_todays_date = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yy")
        End If

    End With


    End Function
```

@Qharr answer is what i would do, you can even create a shortcut to execute the subroutine faster than typing a function..

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! I forgot to add the comment about recalc and hence sub.