# If a cell is changed, set checkbox = True [Excel VBA]

Tags: vba, excel

If a user has made changes to a particular cell, set a checkbox to True. How can I create this? Should I be using Form Field checkbox, or ActiveX checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

Either of Form Field checkbox, or ActiveX checkbox will work but I go with ActiveX Check box.  Check the Worksheet_Change Event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target = CELL("A1") Then
    CheckBox1.Value = True
End If
End Sub
```

Or something along like the code above

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know whether a user has changed the value from a fixed initial value, you can do this without VBA:

1. Say A1 has a default value of "Default"
2. Put a formula in B1 to detect if it has changed: `=A1<>"Default"`
3. Insert a Checkbox Form Control
4. Format the Control to set B1 as the Cell link

Manually clicking the Control Box would overwrite the formula, but you could prevent this by protecting the worksheet with A1 unprotected and B1 protected.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably create that using vba and a Sub type Worksheet_Change.
Look at this thread [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change)