# Excel VBA: Filter (hide) Array using loop

Tags: excel, vba

Im still a beginner when it comes to VBA and I'm trying to write a code that hides rows if its cell value equals zero and the user has chosen to set another cell value to the correct wording. However, the code I wrote doesn't seem to work; I'm sure I have forgotten to add something or am missing some key element but can't seem to figure out what it is.

I have posted my code below. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub HideEmptyRows()

Application.EnableEvents = False

Worksheets("Filtered Data").Rows("7:600").EntireRow.Hidden = False

If Range("J7") = "Filter" Then

    For Each cell In Range("J10:J503")
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next cell

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You just missed the `End If`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub HideEmptyRows()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Worksheets("Filtered Data")
        .Rows("7:600").EntireRow.Hidden = False

        If .Range("J7") = "Filter" Then
            For Each cell In .Range("J10:J503")
                If cell.Value = 0 Then
                    cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                End If
            Next cell
        End If

    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

1. used `With`
2. small clean-up to the logic

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't test to see whether there actually exists a worksheet named `"Filtered Data"`.
2. You unhide rows in `Worksheets("Filtered Data")` but then you check values and hide rows in whatever sheet happens to be the `ActiveSheet`.
3. You did not declare the variable `cell`. `Option Explicit` is a good friend; use it.
4. There is a missing `End If`.

Otherwise the code works; tested like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub HideEmptyRows()

  Dim cell As Range

  Application.EnableEvents = False

  With Worksheets("Filtered Data")
    .Rows("7:600").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    If .Range("J7") = "Filter" Then
      For Each cell In .Range("J10:J503")
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
          cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
      Next cell
    End If
  End With

  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What would I need to do to alter this code so every time that the "J7" input is changed the code automatically runs and there is no need for a button or a manual Run Sub.

Comment: See "[automatically execute an Excel macro on a cell change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434)" on this site.