# Automatic execution of Macro based on cell change

Tags: vba

I'm trying to run a macro every, time the selection of a dropdown menu in a cell changes. I've tried to follow this solution: [automatically execute an Excel macro on a cell change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change)

by entering the following code:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Call Testsub
End Sub
```

```
Public Sub Testsub()
MsgBox "Testmessage", , "Testbox"
End Sub
```

Cell A1 contains the Dropdown menu that should trigger the macro "Testsub". However, nothing happens when I change the selection. I'd be very grateful for any idea, what might cause the problem.

Comment: You probably put those in a public module code sheet. The Worksheet_Change belongs in the worksheet's code sheet (right click worksheet name tab, View Code).

Comment: You also do not need that call statement. Just `Is Nothing Then Testsub`.

Answer (score 0):

The comment of user11138753 nailed it. I edited the code at the wrong place.

Thank you very much!