# Automatically run a macro if I place cursor in a specific cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an advanced filter in my Excel worksheet and I have a macro for the advanced filter with a click of a button.

Once I update Criteria, the report should refresh automatically, without having need to click the button.

(In Advanced Filter, what I am doing is copying output to an Output Sheet. The Input report is in a different sheet. I have placed Criteria for the advanced filter in the Output sheet itself and the Output is placed below the Criteria.)

Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [automatically execute an Excel macro on a cell change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change)

Comment: If 'place the cursor in a specific cell' or if **click** that cell? For activating a cell, your question has been closed with a clear reason. For only placing the cursor, it is much more complicated, but not really impossible...

Comment: Click on the cell for activating..... I tried to make another code, wherein if activecell = K5 of that sheet, then call the advanced filter macro, but it is not working