# Excel clear the cell of the same row but next column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the following exampple, I want anytime I change the value of the cells in column B, the cell in the same row but column C get cleared. any idea how to do that?

[image]

Comment: You want to clear another cell based on the principle of changing another cell's value? Yes it's possible through VBA, not formulae. Btw, column A would be the leftmost column on a spreadsheet. I suppose you meant changing values under 'Department'.

Comment: @JvdV yes, I meant department, I fixed the question. I want to clear the column C of the same row if a particular cell in column A get changed. What could be the right fomula for it?

Comment: As mentioned, you'd need to use VBA.

Comment: @JvdV, I know its VBA, any idea or sample formula? I cant figure it out

Comment: Related: [Automatically execute an excel macro on a cell change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change)

Comment: No, it's not possible with formulae as I also mentioned. You need VBA. *"I can't figure it out"*..... care to show your VBA for debugging purposes then?

Comment: @JvdV It was a typo error, I was meaning do you have any VBA that i can use?