# how to auto run VBA code when cells are changed?

Tags: excel, vba

I borrowed (OK stolen) the following code off another website.

```
Sub HideRowCellTextValue()
    StartRow = 14
    LastRow = 25
    iCol = 5
    For i = StartRow To LastRow
        If Cells(i, iCol).Value <> "0" Then
            Cells(i, iCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Cells(i, iCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This code does everything I want it to do but I would like it to auto-run when a cells value is changed.

The cells are all linked to another worksheet within the same workbook.

when a cells value is 0 I want to hide the entire row that the cell is in.

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409434/automatically-execute-an-excel-macro-on-a-cell-change

Comment: If the cells are "linked" using formulas then to respond to changes there you'd need to use the worksheet's Calculate event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following, inserted into the worksheet code area which will run whenever any changes are made anywhere on the worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    StartRow = 14
    LastRow = 25
    iCol = 5
    For i = StartRow To LastRow
        Me.Cells(i, iCol).EntireRow.Hidden = (Me.Cells(i, iCol).Value = "0")
    Next i
End Sub
```

If you'd like the code to only run when changes are made within your tested range, you could do this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    StartRow = 14
    LastRow = 25
    iCol = 5
    
    With Me
        If Not Intersect(Target, .Range(.Cells(StartRow, iCol), .Cells(LastRow, iCol))) Is Nothing Then
    
            For i = StartRow To LastRow
                .Cells(i, iCol).EntireRow.Hidden = (.Cells(i, iCol).Value = "0")
            Next i
        
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your(?) code to the sheet's code pane which you want to modify.
Rename the `Sub` to

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
```

or select it from the dropdowns of the codepane, and add only the body of the code into it.
Create a reference to the `Sheet`, and add the object variable name before all of the `Cells` properties, something like this

```
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TheSheetName")
```

and for the properties

```
ws.Cells(row,column)
```

or (according to comment)

No reference needed, only

```
Me.Cells(row,column)
```

Comment: It the code is inserted into the worksheet, then `Me` can be used to reference the worksheet being changed. e.g. `Me.Cells(row,column)`